# JQuery testing tools

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, performance-testing

Is there any online/offline tools for testing the performance of HTML/JS mobile application.
I want to test the code and application's performance on simulator/real device.

Thnaks,
Rudresh

Comment: http://jsperf.com/ , http://qunitjs.com/

Comment: also you can use phantomJS for benchmarking stuff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSLitmus is a lightweight tool for creating ad-hoc JavaScript benchmark tests. Features include ...

- Single-file install (JSLitmus.js)
- Works on Firefox, Opera, Safari, IE, Google Chrome, and iPhone browsers
- Adaptive test cycles - tests take ~1-2 seconds, regardless of the operation
- Google Chart + TinyUrl integration

http://code.google.com/p/jslitmus/